# Ruby on Rails MYSQL error Access denied for user 'root@localhost'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error when starting rails server with a new app:

**/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:37:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)**

Here is my database.yml

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: group_chat_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: admin
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: group_chat_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: admin
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: group_chat_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: admin
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Below is the full error message

```
MacPro:FireDemon fred$ rails s
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:37:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:37:in `initialize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `new'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:228:in `new_connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `loop'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `block in checkout'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `checkout'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:93:in `connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1330:in `replace_bind_variables'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1317:in `sanitize_sql_array'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1224:in `sanitize_sql_for_conditions'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:206:in `build_where'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:77:in `where'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `where'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/app/models/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:182:in `observed_class'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:175:in `observed_classes'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:195:in `observed_classes'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/observer.rb:96:in `initialize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:109:in `new'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:109:in `block in instance'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:107:in `instance'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:66:in `instantiate_observer'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:39:in `block in instantiate_observers'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:39:in `each'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/observing.rb:39:in `instantiate_observers'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:46:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/fred/Desktop/FireDemon/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
MacPro:FireDemon fred$
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like your user cannot connect to the MySQL DB. Try these commands in your console:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And when prompted, give the password as 'admin'

If this is possible, then you should be good to go.

Comment: Well, IDK how this command fixes the problem. But I had a friend has the exact same issue, and we ran this to solve the issue: `CREATE DATABASE db_development; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_development.* TO 'user'@'localhost';CREATE DATABASE db_development; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_test.* TO 'user'@'localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES`. This creates the databases, and changes the ownership. Also, make sure to create the user with `CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`. Also change the database.yml code to have the username and password.

Answer (score 13):

The password is wrong for the root user in your `config/database.yml` file. You can always use the `mysqladmin` command to change the root user's password if you forgot it.

Comment: do you mean run "mysqladmin -u root password admin"? Because If I try to run that I get `-bash: mysqladmin: command not found`

Comment: Where is your mysql located? How did you install it?

Comment: @ChrisLedet I am having this problem too (OSX) and installed mysql with homebrew. What can I do?? I never created a password when I installed mysql.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password’;`

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
```

After the above commands try:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 4):

Handy home hint - I was stuck on this too but found that loopback (127.0.0.1) != 'localhost'... I had host: 127.0.0.1 and was seeing this exact problem.  A quick change to 'localhost' fixed this for me... hope it helps someone.

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: mydb
 host: localhost
 username: root
 password: mypass
```

Answer (score 2):

So i was stuck with the problem for a while.

CHECK the file config/database.yml and check your settings.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: ( check what your socket location is by typing mysqladmin version into termnal)
```

Then Go into terminal and type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And FINALLY Close terminal and re open it, then

```
bundle install
```

then

```
rails s
```

It seams like you have to bundle install again for the changes to take place.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question > MYSQL error Access denied for user 'root@localhost'

Apply root user with admin password to your group_chat_development MySQL database

**update**
It occurs to me that you may not wish to be using msQL at all for your dev and test databases in which case change you database.yml file test and development settings to

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

If you do not know how to use MySQL tools then you should get used to using them very soon as you most likely will need them in your production server environment
You will find links to the relevant version on MySQL that you are using here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/
Use MySQL Administrator to set your user permissions.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Its resolved by defining the username, Instead of leaving it blank

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: my_db
    encoding: utf8
    username: # ADD DATABASE USERNAME
    password: # ADD DATABASE PASSWORD
    host: localhost
```

So I just change it for all the databases to the following

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: my_db
    encoding: utf8
    username: root
    password: # ADD DATABASE PASSWORD
    host: localhost
```

And It works fine, Hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting mysql root password for the first time then type following commands as follow:

mysqladmin password

You will be Prompted for new password and confirm password.

After confirmation try to login with user root and password which you have just set.

mysql root@'your-new-password'

Note : You must login as a root then only you will be able to set the mysql password.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you should give the " host: " field in the devlepment in database.yml file.
that host name must be  " IP " address,like "127.0.0.1" or some thing..
ie " host: 127.0.0.1 "
and again restart the server and type on the address like ' 127.0.0.1:3000 '
here 3000 is the port nomber...

Comment: Why all this tinkering with the ip/port? The accepted answer already pointed to the invalid credentials

Answer (score -1):

If you installed using the oracle package, try login your mysql by

```
mysql -u username
```

Then run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then set your password

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('[password]');
```

Comment: after using PASSWORD('[password]');  what will the password be?

Comment: whatever is in the quote. That's supposed to be fill in the blank placeholder... i.e. `SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456');` sets it to 123456