# Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get the error when trying to run `rails db:schema:dump`

```
Ric$ rails db:schema:dump
  rails aborted!
  Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  /Users/ricardosilva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
  /Users/ricardosilva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
  /Users/ricardosilva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record
```

I have tried as well `rails server` and it doesn't work too. Also tried to reinstall all packs - nothing.

I'm using OS X 10.14 on x86_6,4 brew 2.0.4, rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.6.0, mysql  8.0.15

Looking for an answer.

Comment: "Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" your database configuration is trying to use a user called "rails_user" to access the database but that user either doe not exist or cannot login with the credentials provided

Comment: Either [add a MySQL user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html) `rails_user` or set a different one in your `database.yml`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails MYSQL error Access denied for user 'root@localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886583/ruby-on-rails-mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

Login to your mysql  and add user (rails_user). Then grant the user privileges to the database you have created for your application beacuse it may happen that you already have the user(rails_user) but the use does not have privileges to the database of your application. then go to database.yml and put the require credentials for user which is (rails_user).